# Improving UITableView performance by pre-loading cells

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` where each page's view contains a `UITableView`. I would like to improve performance when paging between controllers.

I am pre-loading some controllers either side of the current page at a convenient moment, and asking for their view to make sure everything is rendered ahead of time. But the real bottleneck is actually the tableview's cells, which do not get pre-loaded:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[vc view];
NSLog(@"view: %@", vc.view); // view exists

[vc tableview];
NSLog(@"tableview: %@", vc.tableview); // tableview exists

UITableViewCell *cell = [vc.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
NSLog(@"cell: %@", cell); // cell is null??
```

As shown in the logging, the cell itself doesn't get loaded until the tableview will actually appear on screen.

How can I ask an offscreen `UITableView` to dequeue its visible cells ahead of time?

Comment: What do the cells look like? Have you profiled it? Sounds like it could be an issue with image decompression, in which case there are some definite optimisations you can make. Could you provide a screen shot of the cell?

Comment: There are no images, and in sure I could optimize the cells somewhat. But I'm mostly interested in why the tableview doesn't load the cells even when explicitly asked for one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's returning nil because when you call `[vc.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];` you are calling the method on table view object, not your datasource (ie your view controller).

This is not the same as *the table view* calling `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` on your datasource (ie view controller) which is where the cell is created, by you.

The method you're calling asks the table view to return the cell it already has for the index path you're passing in. As the tableview has not asked your datasource for any cells at this stage (as it's not been visible), it has no cells to give you, hence nil is returned.

If you want to preload cells, you could create the first batch on a background thread, by manufacturing index paths for the initial rows, and asking the datasource to return the cells. Store them in an array, and then have your implementation of `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` return the initialised cells from the array for the first few index paths when the table view requests them.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. I wonder how much of the performance characteristics are tied to the cell creation vs adding the cell to the view. Pre-loading like this will improve the former but not the latter I suspect. Hopefully it is enough - I will profile and return.

Comment: I'm also trying some crafty ways to determine how many cells to preload for one screens-worth of content; visibleCells is unsurprisingly 0 until the tableview appears.

Comment: Works great, thanks. Plenty of scope for improvement too - next step might be to share re-use queues between tableviews.

Comment: If you know the height of the cells upfront then you could just do a calculation based on the view controllers view height? Another thought, are you using variable height cells with autolayout? Did you find anything interesting with the time profiler instrument?

Comment: So just to confirm, we have to manually call _our_ own (i.e. vc's and not on tableview's)`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  in advance and store the cells in an array, so that the next time _the_ tableview calls our vc function, we just have to return those cells (assuming no changes in data of course)?